# angular module value not injected

Tags: angularjs

I would like to store some information through module's function .value. I configure like follow

**app:**

```
angular.module('MyApp1', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar' ])

angular.module('MyApp2', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar'])

angular.module('MyApp3', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar'])

.value('LoggedUser', {email: '',role: ''})
```

**controller:**

```
angular.module('MyApp1').controller('LoginController', ['LoggedUser', function ($scope, $cookies, $window, AuthenticationService, StorageService, SessionService, LoggedUser) { }]);
```

but I receive an error about `injection module`, which `AuthenticationService`, `StorageService` and `SessionService` are factory and correctly work.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**
Understood what @JB Nizet said. Modified like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp1', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar'])

    .value('LoggedUser', {
        email: '',
        role: ''
    });

angular.module('MyApp2', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar']);

angular.module('MyApp3', ['MyApp1', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar'])
```

Is correct the dependencies? The life cycle must be:

- in MyApp1 I insert some info in LoggedUser.
- in MyApp3 I read from LoggedUser (from MyApp1)
- MyApp2 is stand alone and it don't have any dependecies from MyApp1 and MyApp3.

**UPDATE 2**
This night I simplify the modules. Now I have only 2 modules. The modules are independent of each other

```
angular.module('MyApp1', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar'])

angular.module('MyApp2', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar'])
```

I create a factory for store global variables, this:

```
angular.module('MyApp2').factory('LoggedUserInformationService', function ($rootScope) {

var LoggedUser = {};

return {
    Set: function (email, isAdmin) {
        LoggedUser.Email = email;
        LoggedUser.IsAdmin = isAdmin;
        return LoggedUser;
    },
    Get: function () {
        return LoggedUser;
    }
};

//var LoggedUser = {};
//var loggedUserService = {};

//loggedUserService.Get = function () {
//    return $rootScope;
//};

//loggedUserService.Set = function (email, battleTag, isAdmin) {
//    User = {};
//    User.Email = email;
//    User.IsAdmin = isAdmin;
//    $rootScope.$emit('LoggedUser', User);

//return loggedUserService;
}).run(function () { });
```

but when I Set data in a page, in other the get is undefined.

```
angular.module('MyApp2').controller("MenuController", function ($scope, LoggedUserInformationService) {

$scope.init = function () {
    console.log(LoggedUserInformationService.Get());
}
});
```

Why is undefined?

Comment: can you share your error screnshot?

Comment: Unknown provider: LoggedUserProvider <- LoggedUser <- LoginController

Comment: add LoggedUser service to the module declaration of MyApp1

Comment: So, foreach module I must define the .value?

Comment: @MicheleBoscagin No. But yu should have a main application module which depends on your 3 modules, if all 3 modules are parts of the same application. And in fact, since MyApp1 depends on a value provided by MyApp3, it would make sense to add MyApp3 to the dependencies of MyApp1.

Comment: It's much better if you copy the first page source here, which users can see what files already loaded and what source your project miss.

Comment: Updated with some understand.

Answer (score 0):

count of dependencies that injected by inline annotation must be match count of  parameters passing into function (implicit injected) .

> Unknown provider: LoggedUserProvider <- LoggedUser <- LoginController

above error occurs because angular can't to recognize `LoggedUser` (that injected by inline annotation way) related to which parameters those are passing into function.

> when using this type of annotation, take care to keep the annotation
>   array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration

```
angular.module('MyApp1', []);//set injections you need
angular.module('MyApp1').controller( 
    'LoginController'['$scope','$cookies','$window','AuthenticationService','StorageService','SessionService','LoginController', 'LoggedUser',
     function ($scope, $cookies, $window, AuthenticationService, StorageService, SessionService, LoggedUser) {
    //your code
});
```

furthermore you declare 3 modules those are separated and as JB Nizet and maher said you should have 3 sub-module and one main module and inject 3 module as sub modules of main module :

```
angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-loading-bar','MyApp1','MyApp2','MyApp3']);
angular.module('MyApp1', []);
angular.module('MyApp2', []);
angular.module('MyApp3', []);
```

Comment: Please, more explanation and replace the correct codes

Comment: @Maher i hope i can explain it well

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject all dependencies in your controller.

```
angular.module('MyApp1').controller('LoginController', 
  ['$scope', '$cookies', '$window', 'AuthenticationService', 'StorageService', 'SessionService', 'LoggedUser', 
   function ($scope, $cookies, $window, AuthenticationService, StorageService, SessionService, LoggedUser) {
     // function def
    }
  ]
);
```

or like this

```
angular.module('MyApp1').controller('LoginController', loginCtrl);    

loginCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$cookies', '$window', 'AuthenticationService', 'StorageService', 'SessionService', 'LoggedUser'];
function loginCtrl($scope, $cookies, $window, AuthenticationService, StorageService, SessionService, LoggedUser){
  //function def
}
```